# MacBook Pro mid 2015 turns off within 5sec of boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, power, shutdown

I have an issue with my Mac where it shuts down automatically within 5-10sec of boot. It started out very randomly. There is no physical damage or water damage.
One thing i noticed is that as soon as i press the power button, if i press and hold any other key(Enter/command/option/control/ESC) the laptop boots and works as usual without any issues.  However, the key must held/pressed down through out the session. If we stop holding the key down, machine turns off automatically within 5sec. I have tried reinstalling OS, disk utility, safe mode and nothing fixed the issue. I visited an apple store and the technician ran all diagnostics and confirmed that the machine seem to be running fine and the issue and its workaround are something he never encountered before. He mentioned the issue 'could' be the logic board and replacing the board might fix the issue and that'd cost around $800.

I borrowed a friend's working MBP which is same model, year as my machine machine and replaced my logic board with the working machine's board. And, the issue with my Mac still exists.

I was wondering if any of you have encountered this issue before or even have an idea of might be causing this?

Device info: MacBook Pro mid 2015, Monterey

Thanks

Comment: Could it be a problem with the keyboard? Perhaps the Mac thinks the power key is being held down, which (after 5 seconds) causes the machine to power off.

Comment: I mentioned this to the Apple technician but he said his diagnostics shows that everything is perfectly fine with keyboard and it could be the logic board.  However, after I saw your comment I decided to replace the keyboard and guess what, the Issue is resolved. Thank you for responding. 